# types script how to add new property to declared object?

Tags: typescript

I created a object :

```
countryDetails:Object = {};
```

when I add the property to this object like :

```
this.countryDetails.countryLongName = details.obj.long_name;
this.countryDetails.countryShortName = details.obj.short_name;
```

I am getting an error as :
`Property countryShortName does not exist on type 'Object`

I agree that, there is not declaration about countryShortName. But in the Typescript what the correct way to add either this value or in future values in to a object?

Comment: type `any` might be what you want

Comment: So instead of `Object` should I use any..?

Comment: yes: `countryDetails: any = {};`

Comment: I would highly recommend using a proper interface for that

Comment: @bugs can you show me the correct way to use interface here? highly appreciative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, is much better to use an interface for your data.

For example:

```
export interface CountryDetails {
  countryLongName: string;
  countryShortName: string;
  // other properties
}
```

and then declare your variable of the right type

```
countryDetails: CountryDetails
this.countryDetails.countryLongName = details.obj.long_name;
this.countryDetails.countryShortName = details.obj.short_name;
```